# Segue to certain ViewController with correct information in UITextField SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitextfield, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have already implemented an UITextField that segues to two different ViewControllers based on information inserted into the UITextField if the information entered matches my array {bdArray} then when my button (bedButton) is pressed the view controller segues to viewControllerA if it does not match the correct information in my bdArray it segues to viewControllerB. My problem is i want to allow Segue to ViewControllerA if the first word or one off the words in the UITextField matches my bdArray, then segue to viewControllerA will happen. How will i implement this method?

```
                    @IBAction func bYo(sender: AnyObject) {
    let pText = pTextField.text?.uppercaseString ?? ""
    let pDestination = activeP.map { $0.uppercaseString }.contains(pText) ? "mM" : "nDy"
        performSegueWithIdentifier(pDestination, sender: sender) }
```

this is my code i have already for making the text in the UItextField not case sensitive, which is needed. Any way to add any code to do the part search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to split the textField's text into an array of String, then check if bdArray contains one or more elements in the String array.

```
let numOfMatches = textField.text?.characters.split { $0 == " " }.filter { bdArray.contains(String($0)) }.count

if numOfMatches > 0 {
  // segue to view controller A
} else {
  // segue to view controller B
}
```

According to the code you posted, you might want to rewrite it like so:

```
@IBAction func bYo(sender: AnyObject) {
  let pText = pTextField.text?.uppercaseString ?? ""
  activeP = activeP.map { $0.uppercaseString }
  let pTextArray = pText.characters.split { $0 == " " }
  var numOfMatches = 0
  var pDestination = ""

  if pTextArray.count == 1 {
    numOfMatches = activeP.filter { pText.containsString($0) }.count
  } else {
    numOfMatches = pTextArray.filter { activeP.contains(String($0)) }.count
  }
  numOfMatches > 0 ? (pDestination = "mM") : (pDestination = "nDy")
  performSegueWithIdentifier(pDestination, sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: With the code i currently have it does not work with it.. not sure what to do i am still fairly new to coding

Comment: I edited my post and added the code i am using if you can tell me how to make it fit in as the code you posted didnt make a segue at all

Comment: Can you explain what "$0" i know its a GET request but confused on what they mean?

Comment: $0 is not a GET request. It is called **Shorthand Argument Name**. You can read more about it here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: { } is a GET request?

Comment: @Junior, there is no request being made in any of the code above. It's a Swift closure. You should read about Swift closure [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). I have updated the code, you should accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Ain't been online so couldn't accept. Thanks for your help, I've never used a closure before so it's something for me to get familiar with. Thanks For The Help!